# Calculating minima values for each column of given data

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Can anyone help make this perform faster?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

d0 = np.random.random_integers(10, 12, (5,5))
d1 = np.random.random_integers(1, 3, (5,5))
d2 = np.random.random_integers(4, 6, (5,5))
d3 = np.random.random_integers(7, 9, (5,5))
d4 = np.random.random_integers(1, 3, (5,5))
d5 = np.random.random_integers(13, 15, (5,5))

data = np.array([d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5])  ####THIS SHAPE IS GIVEN, WHICH CAN NOT BE CHANGED.
data = data.reshape(6,25)

data = data.T
minimas=[]
for x in data:
    minima = signal.argrelmin(x, axis=0)
    minimas.append(x[minima])

print minimas    ####THIS SHAPE IS GIVEN, WHICH CAN NOT BE CHANGED.
```

Comment: Why do you need that particular output shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this only works if there are exactly two minima in each row.

You can avoid the loop by computing minima along axis 1 of the `data` array.

```
minima = signal.argrelmin(data, axis=1)
minimas = list(data[minima].reshape(-1,2))
```

Comment: thanks. what about reshaping and transposing? is there ways to improve performance?

Comment: thanks again. by the way, splitting and stacking are also same in terms of performance?

Comment: @alps Actually, [`reshape` docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) state that sometimes it *does* copy the array, for example when reshaping after transposing. I'm not sure about splitting and stacking; I presume stacking involves copying at least in the general case.

Comment: Where does the 2 come from?

Comment: @WinstonEwert Good question. I got it from testing against OP's code. Now that I looked closer, I found the OP's data is constructed to have two local minima in each vector. If the number of minima is different my code fails.

Comment: @alps See my comment to Winston above.